# ifelse matching vectors in r

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
> df<-data.frame(A=c(NA,1,2,3,4),B=c(NA,5,2,6,4),C=c(NA,NA,2,NA,NA))
> df
   A  B  C
1 NA NA NA
2  1  5 NA
3  2  2  2
4  3  6 NA
5  4  4 NA
```

I want to use the row values this df to create a 4th "D" column, based on the following 2 conditions: 1) if all of the values in the rows are the same (excluding NAs), then assign that "same" value to column D; 2) if the values are different, then assign the value in column A to column D. This would create a vector and dataframe that looks like this:

```
> df$D<-c(NA,1,2,3,4)
> df
   A  B  C  D
1 NA NA NA NA
2  1  5 NA  1
3  2  2  2  2
4  3  6 NA  3
5  4  4 NA  4
```

Comment: How is this different to just `df$D <- df$A`?

Comment: @HongOoi and upvoters, if I read correctly, a row with "NA 5 5" would give a `5` which is not the value in column `A`. Still, the OP should have given a better example to show that particular case.

Comment: @flodel is correct; i apologize for the bad example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work (with amended example suggested by @flodel):

```
df <- rbind(df,c(NA,5,5))

apply(df,1,function(x) {y<-x[!is.na(x)];if(length(unique(y))==1) unique(y) else x[1]})
 1  2  3  4  5  6 
NA  1  2  3  4  5
```

Comment: +1 - the only problem I see here is the use of `x[1]`, i.e. you are making the assumption that column `"A"` is in first position.

Comment: @flodel If that were the case then replacing `x[1]` by `x[which(names(df)=="A")]` would work, but it might be better to calculate and store this outside the `apply` loop

Answer (score 1):

Based on @James answer, I believe that

```
apply(df,1,function(x) if(anyDuplicated(x)) x[which.min(is.na(x))] else x[1])
```

might be a little faster if the number of columns is large.